# ¿Cómo resolver este error ? -> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocate is not defined,' IONIC

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic, geolocalización

Estoy trabajando con IONIC framework, y dicho problema me ocurre cuando implemento la API de autocompletar de Google Maps.

Error Completo:

> 3     886874   error    Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocate is not
>   defined, http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android#/tab/compartir,
>   Line: 1

Codigo compartir.html :

```
 <div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
 </div>
```

Codigo en  index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaTyAerQ5pzis73-ojGb2D-Rom3NFiS5s1Y7U&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Codigo en controllers.js:

```
.controller('CompartirCtrl', function($scope, $location, $cordovaSQLite) {

// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

$scope.initAutocomplete = function() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
$scope.fillInAddress = function(){
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
$scope.geolocate = function(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia `onFocus` por `ng-focus` para que ejecute tu funcion angularjs.

Comment: muchas gracias, se ha solucionado el error anterior, pero apareció el siguiente:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined, http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js, Line: 68                                              Línea del fallo: "     autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());"

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con es api, pero hace referencia a que la funcion no esta definida, consulta en la pagina oficial de la api si es que te hace falta algun script que importarz. De todas formas el error que pusiste en tu pregunta esta resuelto con mi respuesta

Comment: @user5872256  creo saber el porque de tu error, mira la documentacion y el ejemplo : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch?hl=es-419